# Proof of expression with integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have had trouble proving the following expression. Do you have any hints to help me?

Let $f:[a,b]$ be an integrable function for which $$\int_a^bf(x)dx=6$$ Prove that there exist $t_1,t_2\in(a,b)$ such that $$\int_{t_1}^{t_2}f(x)dx=2$$

Comment: Which definition of integration are you using (Riemann, Lebesgue?)

Comment: Consider the function $F(x)=\int_a^x f(x)\,dx$. Keep the Intermediate Value Theorem in mind.

Comment: Clearly Riemann

Comment: Do you know if $f$ is continuous?

Comment: @Daniel Oh. Then $F$ as above is continuous.

Comment: Yes, it is Riemann

Comment: @ClementC. Either integral will work.

Comment: @DavidMitra (I'm a bit rusty on Lebesgue integral in that regard -- for a general $f$, is $F$ as above continuous as well for Lebesgue's integral?)

Comment: Shouldn't $t_1, t_2 \in [a,b]$, I mean shouldn't be the interval closed?

Comment: It is true for non closed interval.

Comment: @ClementC. Yes. It's a consequence of the fact that a (Lebesgue) integrable function, $f$, is uniformly integrable: given $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ so that if $\mu(A)<\delta$, then $\int_A|f|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 4):

Since $f$ is integrable, the function $F(x)=\int_0^xf(x)\,dx$ is continuous. From this,  the linearity of the integral, and the fact that $F(b)=6$, it follows that there is a $t_1$ with $b>t_1>a$ such that $\int_{t_1}^b f(x)\,dx>2$.

Now let $G(x)=\int_{t_1}^x f(x)\,dx$. $G$ is continuous. Also, we have $G(t_1)=0$ and $G(b)>2$.

Now, you can wrap things up using the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

These two cases give a contradiction:

- $\forall t_1,t_2\in(a,b)$:

$$F(t_1,t_2)=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}f(x)dx<2$$
so by continuity we get
$$6=\lim_{(t_1,t_2)\to(a,b)}F(t_1,t_2)\le2$$

- $\forall t_1,t_2\in(a,b)$:

$$F(t_1,t_2)=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}f(x)dx>2$$
so we get
$$0=\lim_{(t_1,t_2)\to(a,a)}F(t_1,t_2)\ge2$$
so there's  $t'_1,t''_1,t'_2,t''_2$ such that $F(t'_1,t'_2)<2$ and $F(t''_1,t''_2)>2$.

Now we have

$$(a,b)\times (a,b)\ne \{(x,y)\mid F(x,y)<2\}\cup\{(x,y)\mid F(x,y)>2\}$$
using the fact that $(a,b)\times (a,b)$ is a connect set and that the two given set in the union are not the empty set then there's $(t_1,t_2)$ such that $F(t_1,t_2)=2$.